# Spring Batch: No value supplied for the SQL parameter error with JDBCBatchItemWriter

Tags: spring-boot, spring-batch, batch-processing

I have a Spring batch application in which I am trying to read the records from DB and write it to a file and then update columns for the rows that I am fetching from DB.

I am able to read the records from the DB, write it to a file but when I added update step the application is failing with weird error.

Here is my POJO class:

```java
    public class Student {
        long studentId;
        String name;
        String subject;
        String marksObtained;
        String progress;
        String lastUpdatedUser;
    }
```

Here is my step:

```java
    @Bean
    public Step Step() throws Exception {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("Step").<Student, Student>chunk(100)
                .reader(jdbcPagingItemReader())
                .processor(studentItemProcessor)
                .writer(compositeItemWriter())
                .build();
    }
```

Here is my Composite Item Writer:

```java
    @Bean
        public CompositeItemWriter<Student> compositeItemWriter() throws Exception { 
            return new CompositeItemWriterBuilder<Student>()
                    .delegates(Arrays.asList(fileItemWriter(), studentUpdateItemWriter()))
                    .build();
        }
```

Here is the bean method that I am using to communicate to the
DatabaseItemWriter.

```java
    @Bean
    public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Student> studentUpdateItemWriter() {
        return new DatabaseItemWriter(dataSource, jdbcTemplate);
    }
```

Here is my JDBCBatchItemWriter to update the records on DB and I am getting an error:

```java
    @Bean
        public JdbcBatchItemWriter<Student> DatabaseItemWriter(DataSource dataSource, NamedParameterJdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {        
            JdbcBatchItemWriter<Student> itemWriter = new JdbcBatchItemWriter<>();
    
            itemWriter.setDataSource(this.dataSource);
            itemWriter.setSql(
                    "UPDATE dbo.student_record SET subject = 'Science', last_updated_user = 'BatchAppln' WHERE Student_Id = :studentId ");
            itemWriter.setAssertUpdates(false);
            itemWriter.setItemSqlParameterSourceProvider(new ItemSqlParameterSourceProvider<Student>() {
    
                @Override
                public SqlParameterSource createSqlParameterSource(Student item) {
                    return new MapSqlParameterSource().addValue("studentId",item.getStudentId());
                }
                
            });
            itemWriter.afterPropertiesSet();
            return itemWriter;
        }
```

Now when I am executing the application I am getting an error. Here is the stacktrace:

```java
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter '5': Invalid property '48' of bean class [com.student.record.model.Student]: Bean property '5' is not readable or has an invalid getter method: Does the return type of the getter match the parameter type of the setter?
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(NamedParameterUtils.java:354) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate$2.setValues(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:371) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$batchUpdate$2(JdbcTemplate.java:944) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:647) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:936) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:366) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter.write(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:182) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter.write(CompositeItemWriter.java:59) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:193) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:159) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:294) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:217) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

According to the error I am not supplying value for 5th parameter but in my JDBCItemWriter I need only 1 value in the where clause and so I have supplied only 1 value in the where clause. I am mapping that 1 value there but I am not sure from where it is trying to map the 5th value and also this number 5 is not consistent. At times it will complain that the 2nd or 3rd or 4th values are not supplied as well.

Also, I am ensuring that the 1st value from POJO which I am trying to map always has a value and I tried mapping it with `BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider` and `ItemPreparedStatementSetter` as well.

Can someone explain on why I am getting that error and how to fix that error.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: After making the changes specified in the comment I am getting

```java
    org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessApiUsageException: No value supplied for the SQL parameter '05': No value registered for key '05'
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterUtils.buildValueArray(NamedParameterUtils.java:354) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate$2.setValues(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:371) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.lambda$batchUpdate$2(JdbcTemplate.java:944) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:617) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:647) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(JdbcTemplate.java:936) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.jdbc.core.namedparam.NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(NamedParameterJdbcTemplate.java:366) ~[spring-jdbc-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JdbcBatchItemWriter.write(JdbcBatchItemWriter.java:182) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.item.support.CompositeItemWriter.write(CompositeItemWriter.java:59) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.writeItems(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:193) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.doWrite(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:159) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.write(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:294) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProcessor.process(SimpleChunkProcessor.java:217) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.ChunkOrientedTasklet.execute(ChunkOrientedTasklet.java:77) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:407) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$ChunkTransactionCallback.doInTransaction(TaskletStep.java:331) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.transaction.support.TransactionTemplate.execute(TransactionTemplate.java:140) ~[spring-tx-5.2.9.RELEASE.jar:5.2.9.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep$2.doInChunkContext(TaskletStep.java:273) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.scope.context.StepContextRepeatCallback.doInIteration(StepContextRepeatCallback.java:82) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.getNextResult(RepeatTemplate.java:375) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.executeInternal(RepeatTemplate.java:215) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.repeat.support.RepeatTemplate.iterate(RepeatTemplate.java:145) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.tasklet.TaskletStep.doExecute(TaskletStep.java:258) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:138) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.TaskExecutorPartitionHandler$1.call(TaskExecutorPartitionHandler.java:135) ~[spring-batch-core-4.2.4.RELEASE.jar:4.2.4.RELEASE]
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264) ~[na:na]
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834) ~[na:na]
```

Comment: Are you sure you are passing the correct writer to the composite? You set `studentUpdateItemWriter` as delegate but you show another writer called `DatabaseItemWriter` (this method should return `JdbcBatchItemWriter<Student>` BTW and not `ItemWriter<Student>` so that Spring Batch correctly proxies the writer). `BeanPropertyItemSqlParameterSourceProvider` should work.

Comment: Hi, I made the changes you had mentioned like changing ItemWriter to 1JdbcBatchItemWriter` I have also added the method I am using to communicate to my JDBCBatchItemWriter for more clarity. I am still getting the error but with slight change in the stack trace which I have pasted in the question under the EDIT section. Please let me know if I am still doing anything wrong

Comment: It works now. I did a mistake in my update query when updating timestamp for one of the columns. I forgot to add single quote around it. After adding it worked along with the changes you had mentioned. Nevertheless SQL error message was so deceiving. Thanks for your help